# Syntax error for output to a file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, text, save

> The purpose of the code is to put the output into a text file the problem i have is it says i have a syntax error and would like to know what i am missing

```
def save():
with open(os.path.join('C:\Users\test\Documents\test', 'directory.txt','w+'))#syntax error in this line
directoryScan.write(outPut) #file
directoryScan.close()
```

> the w+ is used for - if the file does not exist create a .txt file and insert the output there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through Section 7.2 here, [Python Input output Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Your with is incomplete, hence the syntax issue.
Also the format for opening should be `open('file','w+')` and in your case `'file'` is replaced with `os.path.join()`, but you seem to be treating it as `open(os.path.join())`.

When you are done, your code should be something like  :
`with open (os.path.join(<path>,<filename>), 'w+') as directoryScan:`

Comment: Thank you for the link it was useful

Comment: Glad! notice that you don't have to close the filestream when using with operator. It closes it by default.